# Website Speed Index for SPA applications

Tags: web-development, performance

I have a large SPA website, when measuring performance is there a standard metric to measure the time to transition between virtual pages? I know about speed index, but that only seems to cover traditional sites.

Is there a standard way to measure the users perception of performance of a single page app page transitions?

Comment: Did you check your site score here ? https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights

Comment: Yes, but that's static pages, I'm talking about SPA websites, so it doesn't seem to apply.

Comment: So you are using single page website?

Comment: Yes, I understand SPA and single page application.

Comment: ok..that is difficult to get performance time between virtual pages..google page speed can give full page load performance.

Comment: please try : http://tools.pingdom.com/

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but will the waterfall report in Chrome Developer Tools capture this?? Have you tried that?

Comment: the chrome tools are fine for local development, but I'm after is real user metrics.